# How can I compare two columns in pandas, but keep the data that matches?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to keep matching ticker symbols in both. I am trying to scrape a few scanners and get a list of symbols that are in both. I originally tried Beautiful soup, but found it a little bit easier to use pandas. I am still learning to use pandas and python and thought this would be a good project.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs 
import requests
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

from google.colab import drive




#def New_highs():
Default_headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36'} # This is chrome, you can set whatever browser you like
New_highurl="https://stockcharts.com/def/servlet/SC.scan?s=TSAL[t.t_eq_s]![as0,20,tv_gt_40000]![th0_gt_am1,253,th]&report=predefall"
response= requests.get(New_highurl,headers=Default_headers)
data = response.text

soup= bs(data,'lxml') # parses the html tags using BeautifulSoup

#read panda url 
dfs=pd.read_html(data,header=0,index_col=0)
NH_df=dfs[0]

##lists of arrays for header data

#convert to csv 
df.to_csv('charts_ticker_new_high.csv')
#return NH_df

#def New_CCI():
Default_headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36'} # This is chrome, you can set whatever browser you like
CCI_url="https://stockcharts.com/def/servlet/SC.scan?s=TSAL[t.t_eq_s]![as0,20,tv_gt_40000]![bu0,20_gt_100]![bu1,20_le_100]![bu2,20_lt_100]&report=predefall"
response= requests.get(CCI_url,headers=Default_headers)
data = response.text

soup= bs(data,'lxml') # parses the html tags using BeautifulSoup

#read panda url 
dfs=pd.read_html(data,header=0,index_col=0)
CCI_df=dfs[0]

##lists of arrays for header data


#convert to csv 
CCI_df.to_csv('charts_ticker_new_CCI.csv')
 #   return CCI_df

#New_highs()

#New_CCI()
matching= NH_df.Symbol == CCI_df.Symbol

print(matching)
```

an example would be from dataframe1 and from df 2 it should output only GROW
Symbol    Symbol
AAPL        GROW
GROW        CAMP
SPCB        BAND

I also get the following errors
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/ops/**init**.py in wrapper(self, other)
363
364         if isinstance(other, ABCSeries) and not self._indexed_same(other):
--> 365             raise ValueError("Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects")
366
367         lvalues = extract_array(self, extract_numpy=True)

ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Comment: `I am still learning ... and thought this would be a good project.` -yet you are asking someone else to do it for you? Please read [mre]. You haven't told us which part you are having trouble with or what is wrong with what you have tried. Your [mre] should include example data - [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: [https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html)

Comment: I managed to do what I needed, now I need to compare more than 2 frames.